# groupby() and second variable

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

```
iris.groupby('species').describe()
```

I am using this code up there and it provides me a summary of all my variables grouped by species.

I just want to see the sum of one variable, I tried this code `iris['sepal_lenght'].groupby('species').describe()` but it didn't work.

Anyone got an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Need to share more info on this. Please share a sample of dataframe with sample input and expected output.

Comment: Please share it in the question itself, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

First, the spelling sepal_lenght is wrong, it should be sepal_length. Also, you may try `iris.groupby('species').describe()['sepal_length']`